# How to get Data-Attr in jQuery in a plugin, and turn that into an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, jquery-plugins

I am trying to grab the attributes on certain selection tags like so:

```
$('tagName').swapper();
```

Each section has like data-image="source", I need to grab each of these and create an array out of it. Here is where I am stuck, I can get each one individually, but not all at once to create the array, below is my code for the array creation.

```
var imgArray = [];
        $this.each(function() {
            var count = getImgAttr.length;
            imgArray.push([getImgAttr]);
            console.log(imgArray);
            console.log(count);
        });
```

getImgAttr is just $this.data("image");

This returns each one as an individual array, not one combined.

How would I connect all of them and prevent them from being split?

Thanks guys.

Comment: why are you wrapping it in `[]`? you should be defining getImgAttr for each image you are iterating over, otherwise it will only ever look at the first image.

Comment: How I completely drop that? I will give it a shot, this was formatted from the jQuery API site, so I am trying to figure out how to do this correctly. And I just took it off, now it grabbing the correct information. Now it is a matter of merging the 3+ that I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely coming from here:

```
var getImgAttr = $this.data("image");
```

this gets the data atttribute value of the first element in the collection within $this. You should be doing this inside of the area where you are iterating over the images. Also, you can simplify the code by skipping the each and going to `.map`.

```
$.fn.swapper = function(){
    var imageArr = this.map(function(){
        return $(this).data("image");
    }).get();
    console.log(imgArr);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! It is grabbing each one individually, now it is just reapplying and randomizing the content for each one. Thank you again!